# How to add a custom Restful web service in JHipster?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster and looking through the documentation I see creating a service here: https://jhipster.github.io/creating-a-service/
but nothing on adding a simple, secured, custom web service.

I've successfully added an entity and can access (i.e. curl) the data with the command given in the swagger description. I'd like to augment that default service and add a second custom service that tweaks the json format returned. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: What you&#39;re asking for is the most basic task one can do with Spring MVC. Have a look at this great Spring guide :  https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
Don't hesitate to read more on Spring and Spring boot before going on with developing your JHipster app. Spring is a very powerful framework but it can appear quite complex for the uninitiated.

Comment: Thanks @PierreBesson and I've managed to get a rest service working though it is not integrated into the security jhipster/Spring provides to entity objects generated with jhipster. Integrating my rest service into the out of the box jhipster security is next!

Comment: Security is defined in the SecurityConfiguration class, by default it's enabled for the `/api/*` route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jHipster starts you off by providing you with all the basic CRUD methods for a given entity that you generated through jHipster. All that creating a service does is provides you with a separate service layer so that calls to the repository are not done directly from the controller.

If you want to write a more specific service other than simple CRUD for your entity then you will need to manually write this code in the controller and service layer yourself. jHipster just gives you a very good starting point. It can't do everything!

If however like you are saying you just want to 'tweak the json format returned' then this seems to me like you just want to edit your entities. If you already created an entity called foo then you can update its parameters using

```
jhipster entity foo
```

In your command line.

Comment: I'd like to maintain the original out of the box entity service and create a second service that has a response with a different format. Based on your suggestion I should update the controller and teh service layer. Thanks!